Falsifying prophecy that is YET to be fulfilled
In the Torah, the definition of a false prophet relies on his prediction not to be fulfilled (Deut 19.1):

וְכִי תֹאמַר בִּלְבָבֶךָ אֵיכָה נֵדַע אֶת־הַדָּבָר אֲשֶׁר לֹא־דִבְּרוֹ יְהֹוָה׃
אֲשֶׁר יְדַבֵּר הַנָּבִיא בְּשֵׁם יְהֹוָה וְלֹא־יִהְיֶה הַדָּבָר וְלֹא יָבֹא
הוּא הַדָּבָר אֲשֶׁר לֹא־דִבְּרוֹ יְהֹוָה בְּזָדוֹן דִּבְּרוֹ הַנָּבִיא לֹא תָגוּר מִמֶּנּוּ׃
And should you ask yourselves, “How can we know that the oracle was not spoken by God?”—
if the prophet speaks in the name of God and the oracle does not come true, that oracle was not spoken by God;"

We clearly see that many biblical prophecies are interpreted by our sages as "to be fulfilled" in the future, at the end of days, for example, the Messiah or the return of a Davidic monarch, even when the scriptural timespan passed.
How can a false prophecy be falsified if the prophet can always claim "It is YET to be fulfilled"?

Presumably it would have to be time-bound.

Yeah, I think it would need to be very specific. It will start raining tomorrow on this mailbox at 3:23pm.

@MichoelR Well, we know they once had schools or training programs for oracles (1 Samuel 10:5 and 1 Samuel 19:18-24), so they probably took exams also.

I don't think you want an exam where the failing grade is the death penalty!

@MichoelR It was probably more about GPSing asses, not the future of Israel. Interestingly, we see a similar tendency with Greek temple oracles who intentionally used very fuzzy and obscure language to let people fill in whatever they felt fit.
